# Matplotlib - imshow subsplots overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to display a collection of imshow (heatmap) subplots on a single figure, side by side and row by row. As a prelim I am testing just displaying 2 fine, and experiencing issues.

See code below:

```
axes = []

fig = plt.figure()#figsize=(10,5))
idx = 0

for symbol in ['EURUSD','GBPUSD']:

    df = get_data_period_symbol('1h', symbol)

    ranges_df = ranges(df)

    # Define x and y as the length of columns and indices for use in setting
    # x and y ticks
    x, y = len(ranges_df.columns.values), len(ranges_df.index.values)
    axes.append(fig.add_subplot(1, idx+1, 1))
    # Get axes from imshow
    axes[idx].imshow(ranges_df, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Oranges', aspect='auto')   

    # Set values for x/y ticks/labels
    axes[idx].set_xticks(np.linspace(0, x-1, x))
    axes[idx].set_xticklabels(ranges_df.columns)
    axes[idx].set_yticks(np.linspace(0, y-1, y))
    axes[idx].set_yticklabels(ranges_df.index)

    # Hide grid lines
    axes[idx].grid('off')
    # Push x axis to top instead of bottom
    axes[idx].xaxis.tick_top()
    axes[idx].autoscale(False)


    for i, j in product(range(y), range(x)):
        _ = axes[idx].text(j, i, '{0:.0f}'.format(ranges_df.iloc[i, j]),
        size='small', ha='center', va='center')

    idx += 1

plt.show()
```

It is worth noting that I get the following error when using plt.tight_layout() just before plt.show()

```
UserWarning: tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer
```

The code above produces the following image:

[image]

The plot ranges from 1-12 (months, on the x-axis) and 2001-2015 on the y-axis. You should notice that the plot on the right seems to start at the same place as the one on the left, and is then stretched all the way to the right. I just want them sitting comfortably!

The overall intention as discussed is to have many of these in one figure, which I will be able to do dynamically with rows/cols once I get this cracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `add_subplot(1, 2, idx+1)`. That is the subplot is defined by number of rows, then number of cols, and then the region ordinal.

Aside from this problem, you might want to "pythonize" your code a bit by auto indexing like this:

```
for idx, symbol in enumerate(['EURUSD','GBPUSD']):
```

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks. Also the auto indexing is a nice touch and clearly a best-practice - will employ that